# JavaScript search system – elements not lined after search

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So, I have an JavaScript search system, which works perfectly except for one problem: if you search something from `<ul>`, then it messes up positioning of items. I have pictures down below, I hope it is understandable. In this picture, you can see that everything is positioned and on line etc.

[image: before search]

Now I used the search to search for the item “karambit”, and as you can see, it’s not lined anymore:

[image: after search, it’s not lined]

So, my question is, is this possible to fix this *lining* somehow?

Here’s the JavaScript for my search system:

```js
$('#SearchItemsFromList').keyup(function() {
    var valThis = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    if (valThis === "") {
        $('#inventory > li > div').show();
    } else {
        $('#inventory > li > div').each(function() {
            var text = $(this).text().toLowerCase();
            (text.indexOf(valThis) >= 0) ? $(this).show(): $(this).hide();
        });
    }
});
```

To show those items there, I am using the plugin [Material Design Hierarchical Display](https://zavoloklom.github.io/material-design-hierarchical-display/).

Here’s the HTML code for those items, which are `append`ed with JavaScript.

```html
<li class='col 2 zoomIn animated' style='padding:8px;font-weight:bold;font-size:13.5px'><div class='card item-card waves-effect waves-light' style='margin:0%;min-height:295px;width:245.438px;border-radius: 0px;height: 295px;box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 25px 2px #232323;border: 1px solid black' id='" + item.id + "'><div class='iteam' style='text-decoration: underline;text-align: left;font-size: 14.5px;color: #E8E8E8;font-family: Roboto;position: relative;right: -3px;'>" + item.name + "</div><div class='condition' style='text-align: left;color: #E8E8E8;font-family: Roboto;position: relative;left: 3px;'>" + item.condition + "</div><div class='center-align' style='position: relative;padding:0%;top: -33px;'><img title=\"" + item.originalname + "\" draggable='false' src='https://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/economy/image/" + item.iconurl + "/235fx235f'></div><div class='secondarea' style='position: relative;top: -129px;background: rgba(0, 0, 0,0.15);display: block;height: 163px;'><div class='buyer-price center-align' style='font-size:22.5px;font-family: Arial Black;color:#E8E8E8'>$" + Math.round(item.price) + "<div class='bitskinscomp' style='font-weight: normal;font-size:12px;font-family: Roboto;font: bold;'>" + message + "</div></div><a class='btn waves-effect waves-light' style='position:relative;left:-5px;top:50px' href='" + item.inspect + "' target='_blank'>Inspect</a><a class='btn waves-effect waves-light' style='position:relative;right:-5px;top:50px' id='purchaseButton'>Cart</a></div></li>
```

Infite scroll

```
var perPage = 50;
            function paginate(items, page) {
                var start = perPage * page;
                return items.slice(start, start + perPage);
            }
            var condition = '';

            function renderItems(pageItems) {
                pageItems.forEach(function(item, index, arr) {
                    var message = 'BitSkins Price: $' + Math.round(item.bprice) + '';
                    if (item.price !== null) {
                        if (item.bprice === '') {
                            message = 'Item never sold on BitSkins!';
                        }
                        if (item.name != 'Operation Phoenix Case Key' && item.name != 'CS:GO Case Key' && item.name != 'Winter Offensive Case Key' && item.name != 'Revolver Case Key' && item.name != 'Operation Vanguard Case Key' && item.name != 'Operation Wildfire Case Key' && item.name != 'Shadow Case Key' && item.name != 'Operation Breakout Case Key' && item.name != 'Chroma Case Key' && item.name != 'Huntsman Case Key' && item.name != 'Falchion Case Key' && item.name != 'Chroma 2 Case Key') {
                            if (item.special == "1") {
                                setSpecialItems(item.id, item.name, item.condition, item.originalname, item.iconurl, item.price, message, item.inspect);
                            } else {
                                $("#inventory").html($("#inventory").html() + "<li class='col 2 zoomIn animated' style='padding:8px;font-weight:bold;font-size:13.5px'><div class='card item-card waves-effect waves-light' style='margin:0%;min-height:295px;width:245.438px;border-radius: 0px;height: 295px;box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 25px 2px #232323;border: 1px solid black' id='" + item.id + "'><div class='iteam' style='text-decoration: underline;text-align: left;font-size: 14.5px;color: #E8E8E8;font-family: Roboto;position: relative;right: -3px;'>" + item.name + "</div><div class='condition' style='text-align: left;color: #E8E8E8;font-family: Roboto;position: relative;left: 3px;'>" + item.condition + "</div><div class='center-align' style='position: relative;padding:0%;top: -33px;'><img title=\"" + item.originalname + "\" draggable='false' src='https://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/economy/image/" + item.iconurl + "/235fx235f'></div><div class='secondarea' style='position: relative;top: -129px;background: rgba(0, 0, 0,0.15);display: block;height: 163px;'><div class='buyer-price center-align' style='font-size:22.5px;font-family: Arial Black;color:#E8E8E8'>$" + Math.round(item.price) + "<div class='bitskinscomp' style='font-weight: normal;font-size:12px;font-family: Roboto;font: bold;'>" + message + "</div></div><a class='btn waves-effect waves-light' style='position:relative;left:-5px;top:50px' href='" + item.inspect + "' target='_blank'>Inspect</a><a class='btn waves-effect waves-light' style='position:relative;right:-5px;top:50px' id='purchaseButton'>Cart</a></div></li>");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
            var win = $(window);
            var page = 0;
            renderItems(paginate(items, page));
            win.scroll(function() {
                if ($(document).height() - win.height() == win.scrollTop()) {
                    page++;
                    renderItems(paginate(items, page));
                }
            });
```

Comment: Please, this is not a good stackoverflow question with all elements all shown in just one line.

Comment: Plus, why not directly show us the url, but an image? Only by giving url could help be provided

Comment: In one line, it's because it's compressed.. & it's on my localhost at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With an active filter, you are only hiding the inner `div`s but not their parent `li`s. I guess their padding causes the mess up. Try to change your code to:

```
$('#SearchItemsFromList').keyup(function() {
    var valThis = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    if (valThis === "") {
        // find li not li > div
        $('#inventory > li').show();
    } else {
        // same here
        $('#inventory > li').each(function() {
            // use inner div for text comparison
            var text = $(this).find('> div').text().toLowerCase();
            // this is shorter to show/hide by true/false
            $(this).toggle(text.indexOf(valThis) >= 0);
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks! it works, but one more thing.. Now if I delete the `letter(s)` from the box, then it reloads all the items and also.. Is this possible to `redo` all the search system? I have an infinite scroll on my site and if I search item which is not yet `showed` it doesn't search for it.. Can I somehow change it?

Comment: The current code searches text in the DOM and it should respect new items that get added to the DOM. But it can't search items that are yet to be loaded by infinite scroll via ajax. In that case, you should change the infinite scroll ajax call, so that searching happens on the server and delivers only filtered results. It could then properly load the next chunk of search results by infinite scroll.

Comment: Oh.. My infinite scroll is kind of a different, I'll edit my first post.

Comment: Alright, I added my `infinite scroll` it has that item card appending in as well.